# ItemSend event addin for outlook on the web is not working for classic web version but it is working on new Outlook on the web version

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

I have developed a web addin for outlook. This is an on send feature for outlook web email. This is working as expected for the 'the new Outlook on the web' version of office 365 but is not working for the classic web version of office 365.

Answer (score 0):

to enable the on-send feature on classic (old) OWA, you have to request your admin to run cmdlets as described in the URL here
[Enabling onSend for classic OWA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=classic#install-outlook-add-ins-that-use-on-send)

Classic OWA will cutover to the New OWA shortly. Classic OWA will be retained only for on-prem users